# Layout view in MS Teams is completely different from Azure portal Test in Webchat console, how can I fix it?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I created a bot which I integrated with MS Teams channel. The layout view as shown in the WebChat window and emulator is perfect which is exactly what I need but when I deployed my bot with MS Teams, the view looks messed up and very cluttered. Any advice how to fix this?

[MS Teams view layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqv6D.png)

[Azure portal Webchat console view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csTCr.png)

Please excuse my shortcomings as I am a new user to Stackoverflow and don't know how to address questions but if there are any suggestions for this issue, those would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please try out the [cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards) supported by Microsoft Teams to give a rich UI to the content you want to display inside Teams.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT thanks so much for this, I have been exploring adaptive cards after you mentioned those here. Really appreciate your efforts to help.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Hi! So I managed to find a way to use the adaptive cards.json file with my bot code but now I am having issues with entering urls in the adaptive card. See, my urls are dynamic, they are coming from a database and I have used a third party database API to leverage that data so I have no way of hard coding these urls as I don't know what kind of query the user will type. Is there a way that I could implement my API logic inside that adaptive card?

Comment: Please use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57445388/trying-to-use-adaptive-cards-to-get-a-better-view-layout-in-ms-teams-for-my-azur) for using links with Adaptive cards

Comment: Thanks for the help @Gousia-MSFT That post is also mine.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using markdown in an Adaptive Card.

**Bot Framework SDK v4 (Node)**

```
await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard({
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [
      {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "Top Options:  \nOption 1: [https://microsoft.com](https://microsoft.com)  \nOption 2: [https://microsoft.com](https://microsoft.com)  \nOptions 3: [https://microsoft.com](https://microsoft.com)"
      }
  ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
})] });
```

**Teams Screenshot**
[image]

**Web Chat Screenshot**

[image]

Note, rendering behaviors do differ across different platforms.

Hope this helps!

Comment: please excuse my dumb question. I had no idea what visual studio code was until I saw this json guide that you showed above. I am very new to all this and have absolutely no idea how to deploy these adaptive cards with my bot. So I have made my own adaptive card like I want it similar to yours with the designer window in adaptivecards.io. Now, how do I implement the C# logic for this adaptive card with my bot code? Do I do it in the bot.cs file in visual studio, basically where do I implement all this? Please help out if possible. Really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Hi! So I managed to find a way to use the adaptive cards.json file with my bot code but now I am having issues with entering urls in the adaptive card. See, my urls are dynamic, they are coming from a database and I have used a third party database API to leverage that data so I have no way of hard coding these urls as I don't know what kind of query the user will type. Is there a way that I could implement my API logic inside that adaptive card?

Comment: I would recommend looking at the [Adaptive Cards](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AdaptiveCards/) NuGet Package if you want to build custom cards in C#. Otherwise, you have to modify the JSON in C# which can be tedious. I would also recommend you look at the Bot Framework [Using Cards](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/06.using-cards) sample.

Comment: Thanks a lot @tdurnford I will look into this. Appreciate all the help.

Comment: @user458622 Marking the solution as accepted serves the greater Stack Overflow community and anyone with a similar question. If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it. If not, let me know how else I can help!